# Как покерклиенты опрееляют дубли аккаунтов?

Tags: железо

планирую запускать один проект для pc, но интересует способ выявления "дублей аккаунтов".

Как это делать через web я понимаю. как проверять ip тоже.

Но меня интересуют "железные параметры". Т.е. id материнской платы, винчестера и т.д.

насколько я понимаю, с этим лучше всего сейчас борятся различные покер клиенты.

То что они проверяют активность внутри и прочие аномалии в действиях в самой игре  - это понятно.

Что проверяют на "виртуалку" - тоже понятно.

Интересует именно какие есть способы проверить с точки зрения железа что перед тобой два одинаковых компьютера.

на этом же сайте нашел ответ, что потенциальных параметров 5:

```
 CPUID
SMBIOS System UUID
Серийный номер системника
Серийный номер материнской платы
MAC
```

Вопрос, есть ли еще параметры?

Comment: Есть такая вещь в интернете, как цифровой отпечаток. Это то, что тебе нужно для браузера, для других можешь свой аналог написать, если изучишь принцип
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: Про браузер понятно, но вопрос про железо